# On merge cell how to apply thick box border?

Tags: java, spring, apache, apache-poi

Apache Poi, I am using `XSSFWorkbook`, `XSSFCell`, `XSSFFont` and `XSSFCellStyle` in Java code. On merge cell how can I apply thick box border on cell?

Answer (score 0):

// Create a cell and put a value in it.

```
Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(4);
```

// Style the cell with borders all around.

```
   CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle(); 
    style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    style.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    style.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    style.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
    style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    style.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
    style.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM_DASHED);
    style.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Iterate over this if required .

Comment: in merge cell its not reflecting.

Comment: First you have to apply border on all cells which you want to merge  than merge it. it works'